# Deserialize @JsonUnwrapped Optional<> field using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, option-type, jackson-databind

I tried to apply `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to `Optional<>` field and can't figure out why deserialization turns this field into null value.

I wrote a test to demonstrate this issue and marked a place where the test fails: `// throws java.lang.AssertionError`

Tried this with `jackson-databind:2.9.10.4` and `jackson-databind:2.11.0` using corresponding version of `jackson-datatype-jdk8`. The result is the same.

```
public class JacksonTest {
    public static class Person {
        @JsonUnwrapped
        public MainData mainData;
        @JsonUnwrapped
        public Optional<AdditionalData> additionalData;
    }

    public static class MainData {
        public String name;
    }

    public static class AdditionalData {
        public String address;
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonUnwrappedWithOptionalTest() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

        Person expected = new Person();
        expected.mainData = new MainData();
        expected.mainData.name = "Homer";
        expected.additionalData = Optional.of(new AdditionalData());
        expected.additionalData.get().address = "Springfield";

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(expected);

        assertThat(json, is("{\"name\":\"Homer\",\"address\":\"Springfield\"}"));

        Person actual = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);

        assertNotNull(actual.mainData);
        assertThat(actual.mainData.name, is("Homer"));
        assertNotNull(actual.additionalData); // throws java.lang.AssertionError; actual.additionalData is null
        assertThat(actual.additionalData.isPresent(), is(true));
        assertThat(actual.additionalData.get().address, is("Springfield"));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or may be it's just a bug?

**WORKAROUND:** Finally, I added a custom deserializer using `@JsonDeserialize` as a workaround but I would like to find a right solution.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely to be a bug which may be posted to [Jackson's Git](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+optional)

Comment: Alex, thank you. I've tried to find something corresponding in Jackson's Git. I'm gonna do this if the answer is not found.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2736